# When using databinding in VB.NET, how can I format the date value in a textbox?

Tags: vb.net

I have created a form on which is a textbox that holds a date, Delivery Date. Its text property is bound to a DeliveryDate property of an RFQ class that I created to handle all the dealings with SQL Server. I have tried this way:

```
 tbDeliveryDate.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", RFQ, 
      "DeliveryDate", False, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
```

but the date and time both appear in the textbox and it behaves weirdly when you try to use it. I tried this way:

```
tbDeliveryDate.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", RFQ, 
  "DeliveryDate", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, 
  DBNull.Value, "MM/dd/yy"))
```

but the property value doesn't receive the textbox value. What am I missing?

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, XAML, or ASP.NET WebForms?

Comment: WinForms, sorry I should have saaid

Answer (score 1):

Use `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation` :

```
tbDeliveryDate.DataBindings.Add("Text", RFQ, "DeliveryDate", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, "", "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello have you tried to convert it for example

```
Dim tbDeliveryDate as Date

tbDeliveryDate = Date(txtDeliverydate).Text))
```

Comment: But if I bind the text property of the textbox to the property from my RFQ class - I am not sure how that would work. Normally, this is kind of how I would do it, but this is my first try at using databinding rather than handling it all manually.

Answer (score 0):

It's work using below code:

```
Me.txtLimitKredit.DataBindings.Add("Text", BinSource, "limitkredit", True).FormatString = "##,##0"

*descr:
txtLimitKredit: text name
BinSource: BindingSource
limitkredit: filed name*
```

Comment: Please use proper code formatting since it's hard to read this answer.